# Use SilverLight Reporting in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I am new to silverlight reporting.I want to know how to use silverlight reporting with MVC application.I already used Crystal report but I now have to use Silverlight in mVC application. Provide some links.All Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stimulreport](http://stimulsoft.com/)
this report for [silvelight](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products/reports-silverlight) use in asp and use native